# Corestriction of a continuous function remains continuous

Tags: general-topology

Let $\beta: J \to \mathbb{R^3}$ be a continuous function and $M \subset \mathbb{R^3} $. How can I show that $\beta|^{M}: J \to M$ is still continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should assume $\beta[J] \subseteq M$ where $[\cdot]$ represents the image of a mapping. Let $V$ be an open subset of $M$. Then, there is an open subset $S$ of $ \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $S \cap M = V$. Furthermore, $(\beta|^{M})^{-1}[V]  = \beta^{-1}[S]$. Meanwhile, $\beta^{-1}[S]$ is open in $J$ since $\beta$ is continuous, hence $(\beta|^{M})^{-1}[V]$.